# Why does this script give me a type error? Function to get images in javascript localstorage

Tags: javascript, base64, local-storage

I made a script which takes an image from a form input and prepares it to be put in javascript localstorage. The script is below:

```
    bannerImage = document.getElementById('image');
    imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);

    function getBase64Image(img) {
        // Create an empty canvas element
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        // Copy the image contents to the canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Get the data-URL formatted image
        // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
        // original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    }

    // Create new JSON entry
    var json_entry = {'title': titleField.val(),
                        'image': imgData,
                        'content': contentField.val(),
                        'location': location};
```

The problem is that I get an error when i submit the form:

```
[Error] TypeError: Type error
getBase64Image (script.js, line 138)
submitForm (script.js, line 128)
dispatch (jquery.min.js, line 3)
i (jquery.min.js, line 3)
```

The line from the error is `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `bannerImage`?

Comment: It's a file input field

Comment: `drawImage` requires it to be an `img` element.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()): _the specification permits any image element (that is, <img>, <canvas>, and <video>)_

Comment: But if i select an image as value for the input field it should work right? And if not, how can I make this work?

Comment: You have to upload the image file to the server, and it should send back a URL that you can reference in the `src` attribute of an image. Then you can draw that image onto a canvas. Or you could skip the canvas and have the server send back the base64 encoding, which you then put into localstorage.

Comment: Are you actually uploading the image so that it is displayed on the page before you try to read it? @Barmar is right, it has to be actually rendered in the DOM before you can write it to the canvas. I did a quick JSFiddle with your code and an image on the page and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kYss6/

Comment: it seems like he's trying to do the same thing as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007106/how-can-i-get-an-images-data-in-base64-from-a-file-input-without-filereader-in