# How can I get an images data in base64 from a file input without FileReader() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, input, base64, filereader

Is there a way to get the image data without FileReader()?

I'm looking for an older non-browser specific way to do it in javascript.

Comment: Is this any relationship to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006569/why-does-this-script-give-me-a-type-error-function-to-get-images-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment29789355_20006569

Comment: you can upload it to an echo server, but you can't use only JS.

Comment: @Barmar I suppose are questions are similar. Although he should just use FileReader() to read the image in the input. Unfortunately I'm trying to do it specifically without FileReader or loading the onto a server. Is there no way to get a local images' base64 data without using those 2 options?